# How to fix "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" error after deploying PWA (Progressive Web App) to Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, progressive-web-apps

I'm am working with Google Codelabs PWA Official Tutorial(https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/your-first-pwapp) and works fine with local ip server.B But when I try to deploying the project to Firebase, I find that the weather forecast keep loading and cannot get the result. It seems like failed to load forecast data from network.

The console error indicated the error with "https://pwa-10223.firebaseapp.com/forecast/40.7720232,-73.9732319 "

The file error "Failed to load resource,the server respond with the status of 404()" appeared in the line "return fetch(`/forecast/${coords}`)"

How can I fix the error to get the data from network?

I have tried this code with node server.js and it works, but after access it throught Firebase it keep loading.

```
/**
 * Get's the latest forecast data from the network.
 *
 * @param {string} coords Location object to.
 * @return {Object} The weather forecast, if the request fails, return null.
 */

#Failed to load resource,the server respond with the status of 404()
function getForecastFromNetwork(coords) { 
  return fetch(`/forecast/${coords}`)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .catch(() => {
        return null;
      });
}
```

Comment: the resource doesn't exist (that's what a 404 is) - the problem is possibly your server code

Comment: It works perfectly when I assess localhost:8000 calling node server.js in vscode

Comment: ok, so how is the server at localhost:8000 different to the server that has the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The [setup instructions](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/#1) are designed for [glitch.com](https://glitch.com) an will not work directly with Firebase without some modifications.

Firebase Hosting will only serve files and will not run a Node.js server. You'll have to take the code in [`server.js`](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/your-first-pwapp/blob/master/server.js) and deploy it to [Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions). You'll then have to [map your path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) `/forecast/*` to use the new Function.

I would recommend checking out this [Cloud Functions for Firebase codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions/#0) that should complement the PWA codelab well.